# Content Porter Category Keyword update error

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I am getting the following error while importing a Keyword in a Category.
The Keyword is localized in the source Publication, when I am trying to import I get following error.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040329" Category="17" Source="Kernel" Severity="2" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040329" Cause="false" MessageID="16137"><![CDATA[Unable to save Keyword (tcm:0-0-0).]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_15309</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>tcm:0-0-0</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040329" Cause="true"><![CDATA[Name, Key must all be unique for items of type: Keyword within this Category and its BluePrint context. Source or sources of conflict: tcm:229-1063460-1024.]]><tcm:Token>Name , Key</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_15309</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_15293</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>tcm:229-1063460-1024</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Details>
        <tcm:CallStack>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IDictionary`2)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Keyword.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObjectFacade.Create(UserContext,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Keyword.Save</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Request.SaveItem</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>XMLResponder.Request</tcm:Location>
        </tcm:CallStack>
    </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

This is similair to the question here on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779338/tridion-2011-sp1-hr1-and-content-porter-sp2-error-updating-keywords

### Update:

Error message

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040000" Category="18" Source="Kernel" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="false" MessageID="16137">
    <![CDATA[Unable to localize Keyword (tcm:568-193012-1024).]]><tcm:Token>RESID_16054</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_15309</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>tcm:568-193012-1024</tcm:Token>
  </tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="true"><![CDATA[The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.]]></tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Details>
    <tcm:CallStack>
      <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean,Action`1)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException,Boolean,Action`1)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject,Boolean,Boolean)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior,SqlCommand,SqlDataReader,BulkCopySimpleResultSet,TdsParserStateObject,Boolean&amp;)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean&amp;)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean,Boolean&amp;)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetUniquenessConflictsPost(IDataReader)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IOrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetUniquenessConflicts(TcmUri,TcmUri,IDictionary`2)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.GetConflicts(Dictionary`2)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IDictionary`2)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnLocalized(LocalizeEventArgs)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.Localize()</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObjectFacade.Localize(UserContext,String)</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Keyword.Localize</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Request.BlueprintProcess</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>XMLResponder.Request</tcm:Location>
    </tcm:CallStack>
  </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

Comment: You mention that your question is similar to one on Stack Overflow, have you checked out the answers given there and did they offer any help?

Comment: Hi Bart, we have a option in content porter Resolve shared item with blue print mapping ..By checking this i am able to import keywords too . But when i run a batch update it throws error on some random keyword ..if i run the import only for that keyword its fine ..I have updated the error above .

Answer (score 3):

Your updated error mentions *Unable to localize Keyword*, for the specific details of that error you should check out the SDL Tridion eventlog on the CMS, that should hold more details on why the CMS was unable to localize the Keyword.

There could be any number of reasons why an import fails, most important thing to remember is that if you cannot perform a certain action manually (for whatever reason), Content Porter will also not be able to perform that same action automatically. But because it is part of a batch operation, finding out what exactly went wrong, can be a bit more difficult. First thing to always check is the eventlog, that will hold the actual CMS error, which will tell you the same thing as when you would try to perform that action manually.

Another thing which I'm wondering about is the mentioning of the MS DTC, that might be an indication that one of the operation in the batch is taking too long. Be sure to check that your database is well maintained (indexes and statistics updated regularly and transaction logs truncated so they don't get too large). When proper database maintenance is not performed regularly, your database will become slow and some transactions will timeout.